# Is it possible to add a customized name for the (non file-backed) mmap region?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmap

Just curious whether it is possible to specify a name for the non file-backed mmap region? Some thing like the `[New VMA area]` in the following example:

```
$ cat /proc/12345/maps
...
7fc062ef2000-7fc062f84000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 22688328                   /usr/local/musl/lib/libc.so
7fc062f85000-7fc062f86000 r--p 00092000 08:01 22688328                   /usr/local/musl/lib/libc.so
7fc062f86000-7fc062f87000 rw-p 00093000 08:01 22688328                   /usr/local/musl/lib/libc.so
7fc062f87000-7fc062f8a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [New VMA area]
7fff6c384000-7fff6c3a5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff6c3bd000-7fff6c3c0000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of `maps` comes from [the `show_map_vma` function in `fs/proc/task_mmu.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/task_mmu.c?h=v5.12-rc5#n270). Looking at it, if you want a custom name for a non-file-backed mapping, it'd need to come from either `vma->vm_ops->name` or `arch_vma_name`. `arch_vm_name` is architecture-specific (as you'd expect from the name) and serves only to add a few hardcoded names for certain regions, so it's not useful to you. That leaves `vma->vm_ops->name` as your only possibility, but when you call `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, `vma_set_anonymous` sets `vma->vm_ops` to `NULL`. Thus, strictly what you asked for is impossible without custom kernel code.

However, it may still be possible to do what you want. If you actually just want the memory to not be backed by disk, you can create an FD with the `memfd_create` syscall or a file in a non-disk-backed filesystem such as a tmpfs (e.g., `/dev/shm`, like `shm_open` uses). Either of these approaches will give you control over the filename that is used (e.g., `/memfd:some_name (deleted)` or `/dev/shm/some_name`).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joseph's answer, since Linux version 5.17, you can name anonymous private mappings with `prctl`.

An example invocation:

```
prctl(PR_SET_VMA, PR_SET_VMA_ANON_NAME, start, len, "mymemory");
```

In `proc`, the name will display as `[anon:mymemory]`

Since Linux 6.2, this also works with shared anonymous mappings. So, any anonymous mapping should work.